# Как отправить event в функцию?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код js

```
easypay.core.create(event, success, error)
```

на странице html есть форма и ее изменять нельзя, из этой формы я достаю данные по id, после создаю event и после вызываю event и передаю в функцию

```
var form = document.createElement('form');

var product1 = document.createElement("input");
product1.value = document.getElementById('zip');
product1.name = "zip";

form.appendChild(product1);

var event = new Event('click', {cancelable: true});
form.addEventListener(event, handler);

easypay.core.create(form.dispatchEvent(event), success, error);
```

вот ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.preventDefault is not a function
```

что делаю не так? в js не силен, заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Функция [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) первым аргументом ожидает строку. Если нужен клик, то передаём "click".

Можно посмотреть на примере [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/jt9es7qt/1/). Для того, чтобы была видна работа, добавил задержку. Вы можете убрать вызов `setTimeout`.

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: А где именно выдаётся ошибка? В easypay?
На счёт dispatchEvent могу сказать, что она возвращает true/false (почитать можно здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). А что принимает функция create в easypay.core первым параметром: bool или event? Думаю, ожидается event. Поэтому, попробуйте передавать не результат функции, а сам event. Без самой библиотеки easypay, сказать больше сложно.

Comment: `ma("easypay.core.create", function (a, b, c) {
        a.preventDefault();
        a = An(a.currentTarget);
        a = Gn(xn(a));
        return Rn(En(gj(a)), b, c)
    });`

Comment: `a.preventDefault();` - ошибка